# jquery .remove() works but .hide() doesnt

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide

I want to hide a div in case a banner is active. but i cant seem to affect it by using jquery hide() only works if i remove() the div id. this is what im doing:

```js
if (event.slot.getAdUnitPath() === '/1025113/main-300x600' && !event.isEmpty) {
  var $divtohide = jQuery('#ad-replace-card-tag-half-page');
  var $pub = jQuery('.grid-block--flex-column');

  $divtohide.hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ad-replace-card-tag-half-page" class="mrec-to-card" style="display: block;">
```

It also adds a display:block when i do the hide();

Answer (score 0):

You could always try:

```
$divtohide.css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

The .hide() should work (you know that already) and .remove() removes the element completely, regardless of any other script you have acting on that element. I would check to make sure there isn't any other conflicting script acting on $divtohide somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

.hide() method should add display none contrary to what you have mentioned in your final note as display block. This is strange and should never happen until you have a conflicting script changing the styles